# how to resolve this yum dependency error while installing glibc?

Tags: centos, centos-7, yum, glibc

```
Error: Package: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: glibc = 2.17-260.el7
           Removing: glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686 (@base)
               glibc = 2.17-260.el7
           Updated By: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.6
           Available: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.3.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.3
           Available: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.4.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.4
           Available: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.5.i686 (updates)
               glibc = 2.17-260.el7_6.5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a typical multilib problem. `yum` wants you to install the exact same version of `glibc` and `glibc-common`. So you have multiple options from here:

- investigate how it comes that you find `glibc-...el_6.6` in your repositories, but not the exact same version number for `glibc-common.i686`
- remove the 32-bit version of glibc (do you even need it?): `yum remove glibc-2.17-260.el7.i686`